# Why are my shapes teleporting to the center of the map?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, collision-resolution, css

I am making a [Diep.io Clone](http://diep.io), and everything was going smooth until I made a collision resolution system for when a shape collides with another shape. Instead of them bouncing off of each other, they teleport to the center of the map and don't move. The collision resolution for when a bullet hits a shape works just fine, but I cannot figure out why this is happening and how I can fix it. Thanks

Here is the collision resolution code:

```
this.update = function() {
    this.x -= this.velx;
    this.y -= this.vely;
    this.x -= this.pushx;
    this.y -= this.pushy;
    this.rot -= this.r;
    if(this.pushx > 0) {
        this.pushx -= this.acc;
    }
    if(this.pushy > 0) {
        this.pushy -= this.acc;
    }
    if(this.pushx < 0) {
        this.pushx += this.acc;
    }
    if(this.pushy < 0) {
        this.pushy += this.acc;
    }
    if(Math.abs(this.pushx) < this.acc) {
        this.pushx = 0;
    }
    if(Math.abs(this.pushy) < this.acc) {
        this.pushy = 0;
    }
};

this.gothit = function(other) {
    switch(other.constructor.name){
        case "shape":
            this.pushx += other.xvel * 5;
            this.pushy += other.yvel * 5;
            break;
        case "bullet":
            this.pushx += (other.dx / other.mag) * other.ms;
            this.pushy += (other.dy / other.mag) * other.ms;
            break;     
    }
}
```

And here is the full code, if needed.

```js
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.lineCap = "round";
var mouseIsPressed = false;
var mouseClicked = false;
var autofire = false;
var autospin = false;
var tanks = [];
var keys = [];
var bullets = [];
var shapes = [];
var xpamt = [
0,
4,
13,
28,
50,
78,
113,
157,
211,
272,
350,
437,
536,
653,
784,
938,
1109,
1301,
1516,
1757,
2026,
2325,
2653,
3017,
3416,
3854,
4334,
4857,
5428,
6048,
6720,
7448,
8235,
9084,
9998,
10981,
12036,
13167,
14377,
15671,
17053,
18526,
20094,
21762,
23545
];
var tankstats = {
basic: {
 knockback: 1,
 reload: 500,
 bspeed: 3,
 bdamage: 3,
 bpenetration: 1,
 spread: 5
},
sniper: {
 knockback: 3,
 reload: 1000,
 bspeed: 5,
 bdamage: 3,
 bpenetration: 3,
 spread: 2
},
twin: {
 knockback: 1,
 reload: 250,
 bspeed: 0,
 bdamage: 3,
 bpenetration: 3,
 spread: 5
},
flankguard: {
 knockback: 0,
 reload: 500,
 bspeed: 1,
 bdamage: 3,
 bpenetration: 3,
 spread: 5
},
machinegun: {
 knockback: 2,
 reload: 150,
 bspeed: 3,
 bdamage: 3,
 bpenetration: 3,
 spread: 10
},
flamethrower: {
 knockback: 0.5,
 reload: 0,
 bspeed: 4,
 bdamage: 0.5,
 bpenetration: 1,
 spread: 20
},
overseer: {
 knockback: 0,
 reload: 3000,
 bspeed: 3,
 bdamage: 5,
 bpenetration: 3,
 spread: 0
},
};
var camx = 0;
var camy = 0;
var mousex = 0;
var mousey = 0;
var millis = 0;

function shape(x, y, id) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.id = id;
this.r = 0.01 - Math.random() / 50;
this.rot = 0;
this.velx = Math.random() / 10;
this.vely = Math.random() / 10;
this.pushx = 0;
this.pushy = 0;
this.acc = 0.1;
this.update = function() {
 this.x -= this.velx;
 this.y -= this.vely;
 this.x -= this.pushx;
 this.y -= this.pushy;
 this.rot -= this.r;
 if(this.pushx > 0) {
  this.pushx -= this.acc;
 }
 if(this.pushy > 0) {
  this.pushy -= this.acc;
 }
 if(this.pushx < 0) {
  this.pushx += this.acc;
 }
 if(this.pushy < 0) {
  this.pushy += this.acc;
 }
 if(Math.abs(this.pushx) < this.acc) {
  this.pushx = 0;
 }
 if(Math.abs(this.pushy) < this.acc) {
  this.pushy = 0;
 }
};
this.gothit = function(other) {
 switch(other.constructor.name) {
  case "shape":
   this.pushx += other.xvel * 5;
   this.pushy += other.yvel * 5;
   break;
  case "bullet":
   this.pushx += (other.dx / other.mag) * other.ms;
   this.pushy += (other.dy / other.mag) * other.ms;
   break;
 }
}
this.show = function() {
 c.save();
 c.translate(this.x, this.y);
 c.rotate(this.rot);
 switch(this.id) {
  case 0:
   c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 150)";
   c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 200, 100)";
   c.fillRect(-18, -18, 36, 36);
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(-18, -18);
   c.lineTo(18, -18);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(18, -18);
   c.lineTo(18, 18);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(18, 18);
   c.lineTo(-18, 18);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(-18, 18);
   c.lineTo(-18, -18);
   c.stroke();
   break;
  case 1:
   c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 150, 150)";
   c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 100, 100)";
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(-20, 12);
   c.lineTo(0, -23);
   c.lineTo(20, 12);
   c.fill();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(20, 12);
   c.lineTo(0, -23);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(0, -23);
   c.lineTo(-20, 12);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(-20, 12);
   c.lineTo(20, 12);
   c.stroke();
   break;
  case 2:
   c.fillStyle = "rgb(150, 150, 250)";
   c.strokeStyle = "rgb(120, 120, 200)";
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(0, 30);
   c.lineTo(29, 9);
   c.lineTo(18, -24);
   c.lineTo(-18, -24);
   c.lineTo(-29, 9);
   c.lineTo(0, 30);
   c.fill();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(0, 30);
   c.lineTo(29, 9);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(29, 9);
   c.lineTo(18, -24);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(18, -24);
   c.lineTo(-18, -24);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(-18, -24);
   c.lineTo(-29, 9);
   c.stroke();
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(-29, 9);
   c.lineTo(0, 30);
   c.stroke();
   break;
 }
 c.restore();
};
}

function bullet(x, y, dx, dy, r, id, t, s, d, p) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.dx = this.x - dx;
this.dy = this.y - dy;
this.mag = Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
this.r = r;
this.id = id;
this.t = t;
this.ms = s;
this.xs = 0;
this.ys = 0;
this.d = d;
this.p = p;
this.update = function() {
 if(this.id != 1) {
  this.x -= (this.dx / this.mag) * this.ms;
  this.y -= (this.dy / this.mag) * this.ms;
  this.p -= 0.01;
 } else {
  this.xs = Math.abs(this.x - this.dx) / 20;
  if(this.xs > this.ms) this.xs = this.ms;
  if(Math.abs(this.x - this.dx) > 7) {
   this.x -= (this.dx / this.mag) * this.xs;
  }
  this.ys = Math.abs(this.y - this.dy) / 20;
  if(this.ys > this.ms) this.ys = this.ms;
  if(Math.abs(this.y - this.dy) > 7) {
   this.y -= (this.dy / this.mag) * this.ys;
  }
  this.dx = this.x - (-camx + mousex);
  this.dy = this.y - (-camy + mousey);
  this.mag = Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
 }
};
this.show = function() {
 c.beginPath();
 switch(this.id) {
  case 0:
   switch(this.t) {
    case 0:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(100, 200, 250)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(50, 150, 200)";
     break;
    case 1:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 150, 150)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 100, 100)";
     break;
    case 2:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(150, 250, 150)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(100, 200, 100)";
     break;
    case 3:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 150, 250)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 100, 200)";
     break;
   }
   c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
   c.fill();
   c.stroke();
  case 1:
   switch(this.t) {
    case 0:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(100, 200, 250)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(50, 150, 200)";
     break;
    case 1:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 150, 150)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 100, 100)";
     break;
    case 2:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(150, 250, 150)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(100, 200, 100)";
     break;
    case 3:
     c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 150, 250)";
     c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 100, 200)";
     break;
   }
   c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
   c.fill();
   c.stroke();
 }
};
}

function tank(x, y, r, t, n, xp, lvl, id, inv) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.velx = 0;
this.vely = 0;
this.acc = 0.075;
this.maxSpeed = 3;
this.knockback = tankstats.basic.knockback;
this.bulletP = tankstats.basic.bpenetration;
this.bulletS = tankstats.basic.bspeed;
this.bulletD = tankstats.basic.bdamage;
this.r = r;
this.t = t;
this.n = n;
this.xp = xp;
this.lvl = lvl;
this.id = id;
this.inv = inv;
this.reload = tankstats.basic.reload;
this.reloading = false;
this.cooldown = this.reload;
this.timetill = 0;
this.update = function(r) {
 this.r = r;
 if(keys[87] && !keys[83]) {
  this.vely -= this.acc;
 }
 if(keys[83] && !keys[87]) {
  this.vely += this.acc;
 }
 if(keys[65] && !keys[68]) {
  this.velx -= this.acc;
 }
 if(keys[68] && !keys[65]) {
  this.velx += this.acc;
 }
 if(this.velx > this.maxSpeed) {
  this.velx = this.maxSpeed;
 }
 if(this.velx < -this.maxSpeed) {
  this.velx = -this.maxSpeed;
 }
 if(this.vely > this.maxSpeed) {
  this.vely = this.maxSpeed;
 }
 if(this.vely < -this.maxSpeed) {
  this.vely = -this.maxSpeed;
 }
 if(!keys[87] && !keys[83]) {
  if(this.vely < 0) {
   this.vely += this.acc;
  }
  if(this.vely > 0) {
   this.vely -= this.acc;
  }
  if(Math.abs(this.vely) <= this.acc) {
   this.vely = 0;
  }
 }
 if(!keys[65] && !keys[68]) {
  if(this.velx < 0) {
   this.velx += this.acc;
  }
  if(this.velx > 0) {
   this.velx -= this.acc;
  }
  if(Math.abs(this.velx) < this.acc) {
   this.velx = 0;
  }
 }
 this.x += this.velx;
 this.y += this.vely;
 if(mouseIsPressed || keys[32] || autofire) {
  if(this.cooldown === this.reload && !this.reloading) {
   switch(this.id) {
    case 0:
     bullets.push(new bullet(this.x + Math.sin(this.r) * 50, this.y - Math.cos(this.r) * 50, this.x + Math.sin(this.r) * 70, this.y - Math.cos(this.r) * 70, 10, 0, this.t, this.bulletS, this.bulletD, this.bulletP));
     break;
    case 6:
     bullets.push(new bullet(this.x + Math.sin(this.r) * 50, this.y - Math.cos(this.r) * 50, mousex, mousey, 10, 1, this.t, this.bulletS, this.bulletD, this.bulletP));
     break;
   }
   this.dx = Math.sin(this.r);
   this.dy = -Math.cos(this.r);
   this.mag = Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
   this.velx -= ((this.dx / this.mag) * this.knockback);
   this.vely -= ((this.dy / this.mag) * this.knockback);
   this.reloading = true;
   return;
  }
 }
 if(this.reloading) {
  this.cooldown -= 100;
  this.timetill = millis;
 }
 if(this.cooldown <= 0) {
  this.cooldown = 0;
  this.reloading = false;
 }
 if(this.cooldown !== this.reload && !this.reloading) {
  if(this.cooldown < this.reload) {
   this.cooldown = millis - this.timetill;
  } else {
   this.cooldown = this.reload;
  }
 }
};
this.show = function() {
 c.save();
 c.translate(this.x, this.y);
 c.rotate(this.r);
 c.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
 c.strokeStyle = "rgb(150, 150, 150)";
 c.fillRect(-9, 0, 18, -45 * (1 - (this.reload - this.cooldown) / 3000));
 c.beginPath();
 c.moveTo(-9, 0);
 c.lineTo(-9, -45 * (1 - (this.reload - this.cooldown) / (this.reload * 8)));
 c.stroke();
 c.beginPath();
 c.moveTo(-9, -45 * (1 - (this.reload - this.cooldown) / (this.reload * 8)));
 c.lineTo(9, -45 * (1 - (this.reload - this.cooldown) / (this.reload * 8)));
 c.stroke();
 c.beginPath();
 c.moveTo(9, 0);
 c.lineTo(9, -45 * (1 - (this.reload - this.cooldown) / (this.reload * 8)));
 c.stroke();
 switch(this.t) {
  case 0:
   c.fillStyle = "rgb(100, 200, 250)";
   c.strokeStyle = "rgb(50, 150, 200)";
   break;
  case 1:
   c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 150, 150)";
   c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 100, 100)";
   break;
  case 2:
   c.fillStyle = "rgb(150, 250, 150)";
   c.strokeStyle = "rgb(100, 200, 100)";
   break;
  case 3:
   c.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 150, 250)";
   c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 100, 200)";
   break;
 }
 c.beginPath();
 c.arc(0, 0, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 c.fill();
 c.stroke();
 c.restore();
};
}
tanks.push(new tank(50, 50, 0, 0, "test", 0, 0, 0, 1));
for(var i = 0; i < 1000 - (shapes.length - 1); i++) {
shapes.push(new shape(Math.round(Math.random() * 6000) - 3000, Math.round(Math.random() * 6000) - 3000, Math.round(Math.random() * 2)));
}

function draw() {
millis = new Date();
millis = millis.getTime();
if(autospin) {
 mousex = (canvas.width / 2) + Math.sin(millis / 1500) * 200;
 mousey = (canvas.height / 2) + Math.cos(millis / 1500) * 200;
}
camx = (canvas.width / 2) - tanks[0].x;
camy = (canvas.height / 2) - tanks[0].y;
c.fillStyle = "rgb(220, 220, 220)";
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
c.strokeStyle = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
c.lineWidth = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < canvas.width / 20; i++) {
 c.beginPath();
 c.moveTo(0, (i * 25) - tanks[0].y % 25);
 c.lineTo(canvas.width, (i * 25) - tanks[0].y % 25);
 c.stroke();
 c.beginPath();
 c.moveTo((i * 25) - tanks[0].x % 25, 0);
 c.lineTo((i * 25) - tanks[0].x % 25, canvas.height);
 c.stroke();
}
c.lineWidth = 3;
c.save();
c.translate(camx, camy);
for(var i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 shapes[i].show();
 shapes[i].update();
 for(var j = shapes.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  if(i !== j) {
   if(Math.abs(shapes[i].x - shapes[j].x) < 50 && Math.abs(shapes[i].y - shapes[j].y) < 50) {
    shapes[i].gothit(shapes[j]);
    shapes[j].gothit(shapes[i]);
   }
  }
 }
 for(var j = bullets.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  if(Math.abs(shapes[i].x - bullets[j].x) < 18 + bullets[j].r && Math.abs(shapes[i].y - bullets[j].y) < 18 + bullets[j].r) {
   shapes[i].gothit(bullets[j]);
   bullets[j].p--;
  }
 }
}
for(var i = bullets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 bullets[i].show();
 bullets[i].update();
 if(bullets[i].p <= 0) {
  bullets.splice(i, 1);
 }
}
for(var i = tanks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 tanks[i].show();
 tanks[i].update(Math.atan2(-(tanks[i].x - (mousex - camx)), (tanks[i].y - (mousey - camy))));
}
c.restore();
mouseClicked = false;
c.beginPath();
c.arc(mousex, mousey, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
c.fill();
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
if(!autospin) {
 mousex = e.clientX;
 mousey = e.clientY;
}
});
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
mouseIsPressed = true;
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
mouseIsPressed = false;
mouseClicked = true;
});
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
if(keys[69]) {
 if(!autofire) autofire = true;
 else autofire = false;
}
if(keys[67]) {
 if(!autospin) autospin = true;
 else autospin = false;
}
keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

```css
   
            
@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
src: url("Ubuntu-B.ttf") format('ttf');
}

html, body, canvas, p {
   
margin: 0;
font-family: "Ubuntu";
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>peip.io</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="600px"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Additional info:

- [Source code](https://github.com/Priswall/diepio-clone/blob/b3a379072d22ebae4c500cb1e92e21029e0075dc/index.html)
- Test the current version [here](http://priswall.github.io/diepio-clone).

Edit: I halfway figured out the problem, and by logging the collision variables, I found out that they were NaN, so I will experiment further to find out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, I was calling `this.xvel` and `this.yvel`, when I defined them as `this.velx` and `this.vely`

Comment: Good ol' typos, get's ya every time.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will really read your whole code, but one thing I can tell you is, maybe  you should use a physics engine to take care of this for you. Here I will link Box2D for Javascript:

http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/

There is a little guide there too, but you can find other tutorials!
Good luck!

Comment: Could you explain how this would be done? Currently, this answer could be considered as a link only answer because it does not tell the OP how they could solve their particular issue.

Comment: It pretty much means deleting your physics code you have now and use the physics engine instead!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Joza100, but I'm looking for an answer that will help me fix my code, not replace it

Comment: That's ok but your code is too big. I don't know who will have patience to read it. One LAST thing that i can suggest is trying to rewrite it. When you rewrite it you might get it right and not make the mistake you have just made